# make two strings correspond using regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7, bioinformatics

Is there a way to make a string correspond to another string? For example I have the cigar code from a sam file as follows : `77S22M2S`

The corresponding sequence is : `CCCCGGGGTGGACTTCTCGGGTGCCAAGGAACTCCAGTCACGCCAATAACTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTGAAAAAAAAAACAGAACTCCATTAACGCAAA`

Is there a way I can only extract those letters that match with 22M? For example, the first 77 letters in the sequence (77S) I do not want, the next 22 letters in the sequence (22M) I want to keep and print out, and the last 2 letters in the sequence (2S) I do not want.

Comment: You just need slicing: `sequence[77:77+22]`. The question is, how do you get the indices out of the cigar code string? That depends a lot on the typical format of cigar code strings, which we can't draw many conclusions about from just one example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this:

```
^[CGTA]{77}([CGTA]{22})[CGTA]{2}
```

With substitution `\1`.